# SQL Query using calculation in SELECT not working

Tags: sql

the purpose of this query is to take the percentage of late orders to total number of orders. So the calculation part of this query is only pulling back zeros. Everything else works. I commented the part below that is pulling back zeros. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 

        case LM.DState
        WHEN 'OH' THEN 'OH Order'
        WHEN 'NC' THEN 'NC Order'
        WHEN 'TX' THEN 'TX Order'
        WHEN 'WA' THEN 'WA order'
        Else 'Other' 
        End as 'OrderType',

        count(LM.OrderID) as 'Vol',

        sum(case
            WHEN datediff(day, S.Appt, S.Arrived) > 0 THEN 1
            else 0
            END) as 'TotalLates',

    --PART THAT IS ONLY PULLING ZEROS, SHOULD BE NON-ZERO   
    CAST (
    sum(case WHEN datediff(day, S.Appt, S.Arrived) > 0 THEN 1 else 0 END) 
    / count(LM.OrderID) 
    as decimal(5,2)
    ) *100 as 'OTD%'


FROM ((Customers.dbo.CusOrders as LM WITH (NOLOCK) inner join
    Customers.dbo.CusLocations as S WITH (NOLOCK) on LM.OrderID = S.OrderID) inner join
    Customers.dbo.Loads as L with (NOLOCK) on LM.OrderID = L.OrderID)


WHERE LM.CusCode = 'Domestic'


GROUP BY case LM.DState
        WHEN 'OH' THEN 'OH Order'
        WHEN 'NC' THEN 'NC Order'
        WHEN 'TX' THEN 'TX Order'
        WHEN 'WA' THEN 'WA Order
        Else 'Other' 
    End
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  It seems that 0 is a potentially valid response if the datadiff between S.Appt and S.Arrived is 0 or <0

Comment: Its not because TotalLates are pulling non-zero in their own columns

Comment: Right, but the point is you're not getting an error message, you're getting data back that you don't expect.  It would be helpful to see sample input and output data if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to rounding that occurs with integer division, since you're calculating a percentage the value is always below 1, and that gets rounded to `0`, you can fix this by multiplying the numerator by `1.0`:

```
   CAST (
    sum(case WHEN datediff(day, S.Appt, S.Arrived) > 0 THEN 1 else 0 END)*1.0 
    / count(LM.OrderID) 
    as decimal(5,2)
    ) *100 as 'OTD%'
```

For example:

```
SELECT 5/7
--0
SELECT 5.0/7
--0.714285
```